# Valuation of $\zeta-1$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the field of p-adic integer. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $q$-th root of unity , I know that there is a unique valutation on $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ such that this valuation restrict to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the valuation $\nu_p$. I want to calcolate the valuation of $\zeta -1 $. I think this is zero but I don’t know how to prove it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is $q{{}}$?

Comment: Another number, we can assume $q$ prime for simplicity but it can be not prime.

Comment: But you are assuming $q\ne p$, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. My case is $p>5$ and $q=3$, but I’m interested to the general case

Comment: But if $q=p$, then isn't $1-\zeta$ a factor of $p$?

Comment: In this context, $q$ usually mean some power of $p$, and for that case reuns has answered your question. You seem to ask for a completely general $q$ though, which I suggest calling $n$ instead. The "opposite extreme" to the case $n=p^k$ then is that $(n,p)=1$, in which it is standard to show $v_p(\zeta-1)=0$. After grasping that, proceed to the most general "mixed case" in which $n= p^k \cdot m$ with $(m,p)=1$. Can you figure what would happen there?

Comment: When $n=l^k$ is a power of a prime number I can use the property $\prod(x-\zeta^g)=1+x^l+x^{2l}+…+x^{(k-1)l}$. There is a similar property for $n=l^k \dot m$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1} (x+1)^{p^{k-1} n}$$ is Eisenstein at $p$,

from which $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and the valuation of its root $\zeta_{p^k}-1$ is $$v(\zeta_{p^k}-1)=\frac{v(f(0)}{\deg f} = \frac1{(p-1)p^{k-1}}$$